# Hit metal while drilling into wall to mount TV

Tags: walls, mounting, television

I'd like to mount a TV in the same spot as the condo owner previously mounted theirs.

There are 4 existing holes that use Toggler-brand SnapToggle toggle bolts, but they do not align with my mounting hardware so I only used these for positional reference and decided to mount a little bit higher.

I located the studs to the left and right, then drilled into the center of the rightmost one.

About 3/4" into the wall, I hit metal. I've read from other posts that this could be protection plate, but I don't know; I don't imagine there is a wire running there. I've also read it could be a "resilient channel" for sound isolation?

Should I just try drilling above or below my initial point? Or is there an obvious reason why the owner decided to just attach to the drywall only instead of the studs?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Might these just be metal studs? How easy would it be to do exploratory drilling and then patch? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: you can try 2" higher and/or lower.  Plumbing and wires can be run in unexpected ways, so don't assume there is no wire.  Normally if you hit metal, you stop.